# Validate 2 Drop-Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to ask that how do I compare 2 drop down list value so that they can't be same. 
`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Kuala Lumpur International Airport" Value="KUL"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Kota Kinabalu International Airport" Value="BKI"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Penang International Airport" Value="PEN"></asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>`

```
`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Kuala Lumpur International Airport" Value="KUL"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Kota Kinabalu International Airport" Value="BKI"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Penang International Airport" Value="PEN"></asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>`
```

How do I do that so that 2 values won't be the same. Like when user select Kuala Lumpur International Airport in DropDownList1 they can't select Kuala Lumpur International Airport in DropDownList2.
Thanks for everyone that help. :)

Comment: If user selects one item from dropdownlist1,get that item and disable that item from dropdownlist2.

Comment: Hi. Sowjanya. Thanks for your reply. It is possible? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-do-disable-a-combobox-item-in-win-form-using-c-sharp. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks Sowjanya for the link. Will try on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CompareValidator

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="Validator"
        runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" 
        ControlToCompare="DropDownList2" 
        ErrorMessage="Please select a different airport." 
        Type="String" 
        Operator="NotEqual"/>
```

Comment: Hi. Arvin. Thanks for your reply. I wish to ask that can I use the same way for date?

Comment: @CAP2100APR2016 Yes you can.

Comment: Thanks Arvin. Thank you very much.